# Parallax causing vertical scroll issues in Safari (and iOS Safari)

Tags: css, iphone, safari, mobile-safari, parallax

A visit to my site http://instowarms.com will reveal the issues.

The homepage (which has some parallax going on) won't scroll down in Safari on desktop or iOS (latest versions) - tested on iPhone 6.

It is a Wordpress site and uses Revolution Slider plugin as part of a purchased Theme from Envato - the designer is really poor with support!

I really hope someone can help...

Many thanks :)

Comment: Turns out the issue lives with the full width button at the foot of the homepage. I have removed it for now and solved the display/ scroll issues.

Comment: I will post an answer once this is resolved fully.